# Disassembler GLOBAL keyword

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, disassembly

In a disassembly view of a C++ program, to what refers `GLOBAL` ?
I've got a lign which says :

`je 0xb74d334a <_GLOBAL__sub_I_myFile.cpp+106>`

I guess it is a call to myFile.cpp, but I'd like to know the signification of the GLOBAL word before the call ...

Content of myFile.cpp :

```
[include guards]
#include <mutex.hpp> // Functions I use to handle mutex
namespce myNameSpace {
    class myClass {
        public:
            static void stdOutFormat(const char* format, ...);
        private:
            static Mutex(Synchro) // Custom functions from mutex.hpp and others ...
    };
}
[end include guards]
```

Disassembly (I try to be as concise as possible) :

```
[some calls]
call 0xb74d1b80 <os_mutexInit@plt>
test %esi, %esi
je   0xb74d33a <_GLOBAL__sub_I_myFile.cpp+106>
mov  (%esi), %eax
[some calls]
```

Comment: It could be just a label inside a function. Or it could be a name of a static function. Can't tell more, too little information.

Comment: Do you need the code of myFile.cpp ?

Comment: You could add it, if it's not big. If it is big, cut it down to the smallest possible size that disassembles to similar things. And, of course, you'd need to show both the C++ code and its disassembly, not just a single instruction.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: GNU GCC 4.7.2 with QtCreator 2.5.2 based on Qt 4.8.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such symbols are used for compiler-generated static initializers. From the [GCJ mailing list](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/java/2002-01/msg00329.html):

> Symbols of the `_GLOBAL__I__XXX` are used for static initializers - i.e.
>   code that executed on startup, normally before main is called.  Don't 
>   get hung up on the actual XXX - it is just a magic mangling to create
>   a unique symbol.  Gcj creates static initializer functions that call
>   _Jv_RegisterClass to register each class in a global table, so future Class.forName can find them.

This talks about GCJ but the C++ compiler behaves in a similar same way. Pointers to all such initializers are put into the `.ctors` section and are invoked by the CRT startup code before calling `main()`.

Comment: Wait ! You are giving me precious information, you said "before calling main()", what type of code is in that situation ? I thought the main was the real first thing called when we execute a program ...

Comment: `main` is where YOUR program starts, but global objects are initialized before `main` is started. How else would `cout` and `cin`, for example, get set up. It's not like you are assigning them in `main`, right? Yes, it's "magic that you don't usually need to care about, and can't really alter", but it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `_GLOBAL__sub_I_myFile.cpp+106` is just the disassemblers way of making a label. It points at 106 bytes after the label `_GLOBAL__sub_I_myFile.cpp`, which I expect is a "initialize a static object" type function. In this case, it's either the compiler/linker re-using some code [since you haven't posted it, I can't say], or it's some autogenerated code that doesn't live "in a function" (could be an exception throw, for example).